# Finding the problematic macro

Tags: c++, macros, clion

Since I joined the project, my compilation output has always looked like that:

```
[  0%] Building CXX object lib-tests/gmock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/gtest/src/gtest-all.cc.o
<command-line>:0:23: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
<command-line>:0:20: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
<command-line>:0:23: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
<command-line>:0:20: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
[  0%] Building CXX object lib-tests/gmock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/src/gmock-all.cc.o
<command-line>:0:23: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
<command-line>:0:20: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
<command-line>:0:23: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
<command-line>:0:20: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
[  0%] Building CXX object lib-tests/gmock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/src/gmock_main.cc.o
<command-line>:0:23: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
<command-line>:0:20: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
<command-line>:0:23: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
<command-line>:0:20: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
[  0%] Linking CXX static library libgmock_main.a
[  0%] Built target gmock_main
```

And so on. There's always this warning in between of each file being compiled of the whole project up to 100%. This is just the start of the compilation and it starts with the google test library but I don't specially suspect it to the the source of the bad macro. (but it might be) It's weird because when I google this warning, people get a snapshot of the code and the macro but my compiler does not do that, I just get the warning.

I'm using CLion with gnu compiler and cmake on Debian. I've tried multiple regexes to find macros without spaces but haven't found any success. What should I do to identify the macro generating this warning?

Comment: identify the problematic headers by commenting step by step (or with some `#error`) ?

Comment: Could you set the compiler output to verbose and see if the macro will be printed somewhere in the build logs?

Comment: what does your command line look like? probably there is some odd `-Dxxx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @stefan's comment on my question, removing 2 flags from my `CMakeLists.txt` file fixed the issue.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -Wall -O0 -g -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_RULE_MESSAGES:BOOL=ON")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -Wall -O0 -g")
```

I double checked and removing those flags do not hide compiler warnings like unused variables etc. I'm not sure what effect removing those flags can have though.